# How do I know whether a pointer points to a specific structure or not?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

For example, in Linux, I have a pointer pointing to a task_struct. Later, the task_struct might migrate or deleted. How do I know whether the pointer still points to a task_struct or not?

Comment: Please define "migrate". Is the data dynamically allocated ?
By the way, in C you should track this kind of things by yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible.

Pointers only contain addresses, and generally it's not possible to determine whether or not a given address is "valid".

Sometimes you can ask the entity that gave you the pointer to begin with if it's still valid, but that of course depends on the exact details of the entity. The language itself cannot do this.

Comment: Thank you. So if I do not know where the struct is moved or deleted , how can I know the previous pointer is still valid or not without crashing the program?

Comment: what about if I create an int member called flag inside the struct, every time a struct is created, I initialize it to be 100. Then I just check whether it is still 100 using the pointer every time I want to access the struct?  But I still need a way to avoid the crash if it is a segmentation fault

Comment: What I have done in the past for a struct that I create or manage is to make as part of the struct members a signature that is usually an unsigned long set to a particular bit pattern using a hex number.  When I am done with the pointer to the struct and do a free or delete, before doing so, I will clear the signature to all zeros.  Then when accessing the struct through the pointer, one of the things I do is to check if the signature is correct.  However this will not work with a struct that is created and managed by someone else's code.

Comment: @RichardChambers That is, strictly speaking, not valid. You can't dereference a pointer that used to point at memory returned by `malloc()`, *after* you've called `free()` on said pointer. Doing so invokes undefined behavior and is a serious bug.

Comment: @unwind, yes I know you are not supposed to dereference a pointer that has been freed however sometimes you do any way in complex, old source code.  By initing the area to something like a bad signature, there is the possibility you will get a recognizable error rather than ending up totally in the weeds.

Comment: @HaoShen Think about it; what if a struct gets deleted, and then a new one gets created, and the new one happens to be in the space where the old one used to be?

Answer (score 5):

You don't know, because:

- a pointer just contains the address of the object it points to;
- the type information is lost at compile time.

So, C provides no facilities for dealing with this kind of problems, you have to track what happens to stuff you point to on your own.

The most you can ask (and it is alreay OS-specific) is to check if the memory page where the structure would reside is still accessible, but usually it's not a particularly useful information.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your allocation pattern/luck, you might get a segmentation fault (which of course kills your program)...but that at least would tell you the reference is no longer valid.

However, as previously stated, the best way is to track the validity yourself.

If you need to keep moving a struct around in memory (rather than just blanking it and reinitializing it at its current location), you could consider using a pointer to a pointer to make the tracking easier.
"ie.  Everything gets a reference to the pointer to the struct, and then when you move or delete the struct you just set that pointer to NULL or to the new memory location."

Also, in general, if you want to do checks on your program for this kind of weirdness, I would recommend looking into valgrind.

Comment: +1 for pointer-to-pointer suggestion.  In performance critical code, it can have cache problems, but it's otherwise a reasonably elegant solution to a messy problem.  Worth noting that an index into an array of pointers will work similarly.

Answer (score 1):

It is your responsibility in C to write your code so that you keep track of it. You can use the special value of NULL (representing not pointing to anything), setting the pointer to NULL when you remove (or haven't yet set) whatever it was pointing to & testing for NULL before using it. You might also design your code in a way that the question never comes up.

There is no way to query a random pointer value to see if it represents something, just like there is no way to query an int variable to check if the value in it is uninitialized, junk, or the correct result of a computation.

It is all a matter of software design and, when necessary, using the value of NULL to designate not set.